# "Window.Current.Content as Frame" is null - OnStartAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, template10

I just upgraded [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) from version 1.0.8 to 1.1.2 and now I encounter the following problem. In  `OnStartAsync()`  I try to get the current Frame and check its `BackStack`.

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

Apparently something has changed because when I was on 1.0.8 this worked fine, and now the  `rootFrame`  object is null.
 My purpose on checking the  `BackStack`  is to insert the `MainPage` if the app was launched from a  `ToastNotification`  to a specific page.

I hope that somebody can help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at NavigationService.Frame:

```
public override Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var frame = NavigationService.Frame;
    NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```